# How to uninstall .exe packages which are installed by executing an installer through wix

Tags: wix

I prepared a installer which on its execution install .exe packages but while uninstalling the installer .exe packages are not getting uninstalled.

Comment: Need way more information. Code snippets? I would start with putting your ExePackage code in the question **at least**. Putting in the log file from %temp% when you uninstall would also be useful. My initial guess is you have an incorrect DetectCondition for all your Exes so the bundle cannot tell whether or not they are installed during the uninstall.

Comment: Thanks Brain for your reply. My problem is I installed ruby with the below code in my xml code . How to trigger ruby uninstall while uninstalling the installer.       <ExePackage SourceFile="..\..\rubyinstaller-1.9.3-p551.exe"
                  Vital="no"
                  DetectCondition="0"/>

Answer (score 1):

You are using detect condition wrong. Detect condition is used to check whether the package is present or not on the system already.

> A condition that determines if the package is present on the target system. This condition can use built-in variables and variables returned by searches. This condition is necessary because Windows doesn't provide a method to detect the presence of an ExePackage. Burn uses this condition to determine how to treat this package during a bundle action; for example, if this condition is false or omitted and the bundle is being installed, Burn will install this package.

Generally you will use a registry search looking for a key that is added by this ExePackage. Use `Result="Exists"` in your search to set the variable to true or false for use in a DetectCondition.

Additionally, you need to supply the UninstallCommand

> The command-line arguments provided to the ExePackage during uninstall. If this attribute is absent the executable will be launched with no command-line arguments. To prevent an ExePackage from being uninstalled set the Permanent attribute to "yes

This will give cmd args to the ruby installer to uninstall it. You should be able to find those cmd arguments through the installer itself using /? or -? or another resource online.

Comment: Used UnistallCommand attribute by passing the required arguments but it did't worked. Observed during uninstall of installer the .msi packages got uninstalled. Any reason why it is not working in case of .exe packages.

Comment: You need a correct DetectCondition. In the bundle log (located in %temp% you will see in the detect phase that your exe is **not** detected as installed so it does not plan the uninstall. If you want you can update your main post with a (sanitized for privacy if needed)  copy paste of the uninstall bundle log.

Comment: Observed the below differences when uninstalled installer which has ruby(.exe) and python(.msi packages). Python(.msi) is getting uninstalled.[1194:2934][2016-08-10T10:08:44]i201: Planned package: rubyinstaller_1.9.3_p551.exe, state: Present, default requested: None, ba requested: None, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[1194:2934][2016-08-10T10:08:44]i201: Planned package: python_2.7.10.msi, state: Present, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: Uninstall, rollback: Install, cache: No, uncache: Yes, dependency: Unregister